# Select Best priced alternate Material and update Flag

Tags: sql, sql-update, procedure

I have a table with with following keys

1. Invoice Number 2. Material 3. Alternate_Material 
   Non-Key field is Price . I need to find Best alternate material and update a flag in the same table.

For example :

[Table Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTEYD.png)

I am trying a write a SQL procedure which would go through these set of records and update the Best_Alt flag for lowest priced material, in this case 3rd records.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cldmj.png)

So far, I selected all the records in temp table and shorted it by Invoice Number and price ascending .  How , can I find the same with SQL and update the flag in base table ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bad design idea.   You will have to constantly check every time data is inserted or updated to see if the flag should change.   I would eschew the Best_Alt column, and always calculate it at query time.   You could write a UDF to make future queries easier to write.

Comment: hi Alleman, thanks for quick response .  Let me add some more detail .  Data for one invoice number would be inserted only once .  Like , I shall insert one invoice number with actual material sold along with all the alternative possible.  During insertion or later on in a procedure , I want to update Best Alternative flag because while querying on this data set, I would like to use the Best Alt flag as a filter.  In general , I would have more than billion records in this table, and this flag would help me to reduce the number to millions and keep the data volume manageable

Answer (score 0):

I am using rank() to get the best material partitioned by invoice number .